# Is there any annotation to ignore from the change of the response type in fasterxml?

Tags: android, kotlin, jackson

I have an Android app (written by Kotlin).

It uses an external server and the server provide an XML as the response.

Last week, the server response was changed.
A new element was added into the response.

So my app crashed...

To resolve this, I added an annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

And it works fine.

But I have a question.
If the server change the response data type, how can I handle it?
For example, here is the response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <data>
        <sessionid>hello</sessionid>
        <endpoint>https://test.com</endpoint>
        <id>123</id>
        <pw>testpassword</pw>
    </data>
</response>
```

Now, if the type of "pw" element is changed to "Integer" like below, Exception occurs.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <data>
        <sessionid>hello</sessionid>
        <endpoint>https://test.com</endpoint>
        <id>123</id>
        <pw>0000</pw>    <!-- server response type is changed from String to Integer -->
    </data>
</response>
```

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "pw": not a valid Integer value
```

And my app will be crash.

I want to prevent the crash from this kind of change.
Is there any good solution? or annotation like "@JsonIgnoreProperties"?

---

I think that the "Any" type can be a solution.
But this is the last solution...
I want to find a smarter solution.

Comment: They have changed the type perhaps also :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use a custom setter for the pw variable that coerces types:

```
class ResponseData(pw: String) {
    var pw: String
        set(value: Any) {
            field = when(value) {
                is String -> value
                else -> value.toString()
            }
        }
}
```

**Note:** this will still throw exceptions if the type cannot be coerced to a string via the toString method.

For a data class to use a custom setter see [this example](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/custom-getter-setter-for-properties-created-by-type-params/46/4)

```
data class C(private val _propertyWithSetter: String) {
    val propertyWithSetter: String
        get() = _propertyWithSetter
        set(value) {
            /* execute setter logic */
            _propertyWithSetter = value
        }
}
```

Comment: Wow... if the type is not String, I can set the default String value! Thank you!

Comment: If I use this solution, I cannot "data class" right?